# Regarding tumors and their developement

Tags: cancer, apoptosis

If certain cells or tissue in a specific part of the body are for some reason overworked; like the cases of severe acid reflux damaging the throat repeatedly and the cells in the throat having to do growth and repair a lot more than they would with a healthy person -- or problems in the stomach attacking the stomach lining a lot, causing 'extra' growth and repair; could these situations of 'extra' growth and repair cause various cells used in these processes to mutate with all the cellular division and replication required? And maybe some of these extra-growth-and-repair induced mutations might cause the apoptosis mechanisms to malfunction?

Comment: If a cancerous cell has a horrendous amount of mutations and yet it still functions ( if abnormally) it must be able to keep existing without 'alerting' the immune system or interfering 'too much' with other subsystems. How is this possible? Wouldn't all the mutations if 'expressed' cause all sorts of 'activity' the cell or other neighboring systems might not be able to cope with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a positive correlation between gastric reflux disease and esophageal cancer, and also between stomach ulcerations and stomach cancer. There are more than one possible mechanisms for these correlations to arise, but what you are proposing is definitely a prime suspect.

http://www.webmd.com/heartburn-gerd/news/20130523/chronic-heartburn-may-raise-odds-for-throat-cancer-study

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10658066